# how to increase log_message_size() in syslog-ng to more than 8K for specific source only and overide default

Tags: logging, size, syslog, msg, syslog-ng

As per documentation, Syslog-ng allows 8192 bytes length per message by default. Syslog splitting the message into two when size is more than 8K.

When I applied `log_msg_size()` parameter globally and modified value to 16K it works. But I want apply this parameter to specific source only; to allow events up to size 16K and keep global parameter to default.

Is it possible to apply `log_msg_size()` to specific source only?

If yes then where should I mention it in below example. If we modified the `syslog_msg_size` value to 16K is it going to hit my system/CPU performance? Please advise.

Example:

```
source s_tets {
        udp(ip(0.0.0.0) port(100));
        tcp(ip(0.0.0.0) port(100) max-connections(100));
};

destination d_test {file("/filepath" };
log { source(s_test); destination(d_dest); };
```

Answer (score 2):

- You can set the log_msg_size() option globally for syslog-ng, in the options{} section of the configuration file. This will affect every source. For example:

`options { log_msg_size(16384); };`

- To change the maximal size of a log message only for a specific source, use the log_msg_size() option in the declaration of the source, for example:

`tcp(ip(0.0.0.0) port(100) max-connections(100) log_msg_size(16384) );`

Comment: Please add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue